# JSON Encode string literal "asdf\\nsedfgs"

Tags: json, vbscript

I am working with an old classic asp/vbscript app that has a json class.

I have a string literal: `asdf\\nsedfgs` e.g. thats not escaped json or anything. its literally those characters.

So, to use that value in a JSON string, it should be something like this, right?

`{"somedesc":"asdf\\\\nsedfgs"}`

...with the two backslash characters escaped.

However, on the way out of JSON and back to string literal, we'd do something like this (in this order)

```
val = Replace(val, "\""", """")
val = Replace(val, "\\", "\")
val = Replace(val, "\/", "/") 
val = Replace(val, "\b", Chr(8))
val = Replace(val, "\f", Chr(12))
val = Replace(val, "\n", Chr(10))
val = Replace(val, "\r", Chr(13))
val = Replace(val, "\t", Chr(9))
```

...but for the string above, this sequence of replace() gives us the incorrect decoded value:

result (note the newline, as the 4 `\` got replaced to two, then the `\n` got replaced to a newline)

```
asdf\
sedfgs
```

So questions:

1. how does one encode and decode a literal `asdf\\nsedfgs` to and from json correctly?
2. is that decode logic correct? in the correct order? It seems not, because how could it distinguish between a literal `\n` vs an escaped `chr(13)`?
3. is there something else I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part is isolating the escaped backslashes from the rest of the string so that they don't interfere with escape sequences- You can split the string, reattach the missing parts later:

```vbs
Const ENCODE = FALSE
Const DECODE = TRUE

val = "asdf\\\\nsedfgs"
val = JSON(val, DECODE)
MsgBox val

'Swap replacement values & dividers + concatenation characters
val = JSON(val, ENCODE)
MsgBox val

Function JSON(ByVal str, ByVal mode)
    Dim key, val
    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    d.Add "\/", "/"
    d.Add "\b", Chr(8)
    d.Add "\f", Chr(12)
    d.Add "\n", Chr(10)
    d.Add "\r", Chr(13)
    d.Add "\t", Chr(9)

    If mode Then
        d.Add "\""", """"
        d.Add "\\", "\"
        div = "\\"
        cat = "\"
        key = d.Keys
        val = d.Items
    Else
        d.Add "\\", "\"
        d.Add "\""", """"
        div = "\"
        cat = "\\"
        key = d.Items
        val = d.Keys
    End If

    arr = Split(str, div)

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        For j = 0 To UBound(key)
            arr(i) = Replace(arr(i), key(j), val(j))
        Next

        output = output & arr(i)
        If i <> UBound(arr) Then output = output & cat
    Next

    d.RemoveAll
    JSON = output
End Function
```

Comment: This is a good solution to my problem. It's amazing to me how many JSON parsers out there fail to handle this case (and many other edge cases). Read [Parsing JSON is a Minefield](http://seriot.ch/parsing_json.php) to get a feel for what I'm talking about. He tested 50 or 60 parsers against common test cases and no two had the same pass/fail results.

Comment: It just comes down to using a Framework that has good support, personally, I'd recommend this one [JSON object class 3.5.4 By RCDMK](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON) as it has great support and the developer is actively working on it.

Comment: @GWR have just tested the library and it handles it fine - `asdf\\nsedfgs` becomes `asdf\\\\nsedfgs` etc. Which was using v3.5.4 of the library, which was last updated in February. Here is a recent example of code using the library - [Output ADODB.RecordSet as JSON](//stackoverflow.com/a/42417686).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Wonder if iit decode properly as well? e.g. `asdf\\\\nsedfgs` coming in should decode to `asdf\\nsedfgs` (some others will incorrectly replace the `\n` first with a newline character). I will test on my own later when I have a minute free, and report back.

Comment: @GWR while it doesn't create a newline it does do other things which are more worrying. The sample data I tried when passed in using `JSON.parse()` is broken once you try to pull it back out with `JSON.Serialize()` which is obviously wrong. Will likely raise this as an issue on the GitHub repo.

Comment: @Matt note your code sample has one issue on the encode direction... you need to encode '\' with '\\' _before_ you do the quotes... (instead of after - as you do in the decoding) otherwise your escaped quote would be turned into `\\"` - so you need a different dictionary for each direction... but your logic still solved my issue... just wanted to note this for future lookers...

Comment: @GWR I took a minute to edit the code to hopefully account for that issue; Glad I could help out & thanks for the link!